# How can I upload files in one folder when I have 3 language in my website?

Tags: php, image, directory, multilingual

I have website has 3 language, I make every language in folder except home language so I have 2 language in 2 folder, When I upload file I must uploaded in 3 folder to keep the file with other language.

```
$upload_image = "packagePic/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"packagePic/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256',$filename)); //here i am moving the file to this folder


$upload_image = "en/packagePic/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"en/packagePic/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256',$filename));

$upload_image = "he/packagePic/".$filename;
move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"he/packagePic/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256',$filename));
```

so in every file I will copy it 3 times its not good.
What I can do to solve it?

Comment: 1. one time `move_uploaded_file()` function and two times `copy()` function. 2. create a table where put file name and uploaded_for (here enter language name) and every time fetch data from it and  do accordingly (and upload data to a another folder not in language folder)

Comment: Do images change if language is changed?

Comment: no ,the image  for all language

Comment: Yes @Anant , the file same for all language

Comment: @AboYousef16  then best solution is  upload to one folder (not in language just another new folder) and maintain record in db(if every time file will be shown for all language then no need of db, but if sometime you want to show particular image for one language in any case then you ave to maintain db )

Comment: i saved in my DB the path of file , its not possible to upload file in new folder is not in language files @Anant

Answer (score 1):

create common folder and place all files there which require for all the languages
like folder sturucture will be something like this

```
-Project //main folder
  -common   //common folder all files which are common in all languages
    -images
    -css
  -en  //en package site
  -he  // he package site
```

Comment: you mean like this:

    `move_uploaded_file($filetmp,"common/packagePic/" . iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1256',$filename));`

Comment: yes.. just careful for correct path "common/packagePic".. this will save ur disk space and mulitple scripts/code to run for saving one image multiple times

Comment: i want tell you just one who have permission to add files.
its work in home language but others not working

Comment: its safe the path correctly but when i want showing it not appear

Comment: check the folder is it uploaded? if no then path check the path in move_uploaded_file(....). or if yes the again check the path where you are displaying the image
<img src="/common/packagePic" /> //check this path

Comment: @AboYousef16  you folder must have to be 077 permission.check and change

Comment: yeah make the debug on and check why its not uploading.. it might hv different reasons, "folder permission", "allowed image size" etc